# Is there a way to prevent having to specify associations in tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

Given I have the following class

```
class listing > ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :address
  belongs_to :owner

  validates :owner_id, presence: true
  validates :address, presence: true
end
```

Is there a way I can get away with not having to keep associating an owner before I save a listing in my tests in `/spec/models/listing_spec.rb`, without making `owner_id` accessible through mass assignment?

```
describe Listing do
  before(:each) do
    @owner = Factory :owner
    @valid_attr = {
      address: 'An address',
    }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    listing = Listing.new @valid_attr
    listing.owner = @owner
    listing.save!
  end

  it "should require an address" do
    listing = Listing.new @valid_attr.merge(:address => "")
    listing.owner = @owner
    listing.should_not be_valid
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is if you use [factory-girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)

```
  # it's probably not a good idea to use FG in the first one
  it "should create a new instance given valid attributes" do
    listing = Listing.new @valid_attr
    listing.owner = @owner
    listing.property_type = Factory(:property_type)
    listing.save!
  end

  it "should require an address" do
    # But here you can use it fine
    listing = Factory.build :listing, address: ''
    listing.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require a reasonable short address" do
    listing = Factory.build :listing, address: 'a'*245
    listing.should_not be_valid
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use factory-girl (unless you want to...):

```
let(:valid_attributes) { address: 'An Address', owner_id: 5}

it "creates a new instance with valid attributes" do
  listing = Listing.new(valid_attributes)
  listing.should be_valid
end

it "requires an address" do
  listing = Listing.new(valid_attributes.except(:address))
  listing.should_not be_valid
  listing.errors(:address).should include("must be present")
end

it "requires an owner_id" do
  listing = Listing.new(valid_attributes.except(:owner_id))
  listing.should_not be_valid
  listing.errors(:owner_id).should include("must be present")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I hate to be the voice of dissent here, but you shouldn't be calling `save!` or `valid?` **at all** in your validation spec. And 9 times out of 10, if you need to use factory girl just to check the validity of your model, something is very wrong. What you should be doing is checking for errors on each of the attributes.

A better way to write the above would be:

```
describe Listing do
  describe "when first created" do
    it { should have(1).error_on(:address) }
    it { should have(1).error_on(:owner_id) }
  end
end
```

Also, chances are you don't want to be checking for the **presence** of an address, you want to check that it is not nil, not an empty string, and that it is not longer than a certain length.  You'll want to use `validates_length_of` for that.